# How to pass a Array through Context native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context

Hi Dear thank you for turning in to my question , I am trying  pass a array from one component to another using react-native context below is my try but it is not working for arrays

```
import React from 'react';


var context = {
    playlist: null, //like I want to make this value a array
    setPlaylist: (songID: string) => {

    }
}

export var playlistContext = React.createContext(context);
```

My App.tsx file

```
const [playlist, setPlaylist] = useState<string | null>(null);

<playlistContext.Provider value={{
    playlist,
    setPlaylist: (songID: string) => setPlaylist(songID),
}}>
    <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
    <StatusBar />
    <PlayerWidget />
</playlistContext.Provider>
```

Comment: What is the actual question for this post?

Comment: Seems you can update the `playlist` state with some array data and it will be passed in the context value. Is there an issue or question buried in your post somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer by reforming the the playlistContext.tsx context API like below:

```
import React from 'react';


var context = {
    playlist: [],
    setPlaylist: (songID: string[]) => {

    }

}

export var playlistContext = React.createContext(context);
```

Then I did this in my App.tsx so has to consume it in the provider

```
const [playlist, setPlaylist] = useState<string | string[]>([]);
 <playlistContext.Provider value={{
                    playlist,
                    setPlaylist: (songID: string[]) => setPlaylist(songID),

                  }}>

                    <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
                    <StatusBar />
                    <PlayerWidget />
                  </playlistContext.Provider>
```